# Load a java class and run its method provided by a string

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that will run a method given the code as a string.

Here is an example:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String code = "public class Test { public static void test() { System.out.println(\"This is a test!\"; } }";

    // somehow load that string as a class

    // then run the method Test.test() and have the results printed

}
```

If this is possible or has been done before, I'd greatly appreciate a direction to take to achieve this.

Comment: Please provide details of What have you tried?

Comment: Compiling Java source code to Java byte code at run-time is pretty complex. You may rethink if you really need this. Alternatively you could look at scripting languages like Apache Groovy - they also run in a JVM.

Comment: Thanks @Robert, it was just an idea of a test I was trying to do. I don't need it for anything specifically other than to see if I was capable of achieving it.

Comment: Please read https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-compile-a-class-at-runtime-with-java-8-and